# Decorator which changes ints to strings with correct type hints

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have written a decorator which changes the types of some arguments passed to a decorated function.

For example, any argument which was `int` should become `str`:

```py
from typing import Callable

def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        modified_args = [str(arg) if isinstance(arg, int) else arg for arg in args]
        return func(*modified_args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def my_function(a: int | str, b: int) -> str:
    return a + b

result = my_function('foo', 4)
print(result)
```

Running this code outputs `'foo4'`, as expected.

However, according to `mypy` the typing is incorrect:

```py
t.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[int, Any]", expected "str")  [return-value]
t.py:12: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")  [operator]
t.py:12: note: Left operand is of type "Union[int, str]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a way to type `decorator` so that the within the body of `my_function`, mypy will know that any argument of type `int` has been transformed to `str`?

Comment: Note that the correct annotation for `my_function` would be `a: str, b: str` - it's only the *decorated* `my_function` that accepts `a: str | int, b: str | int` and it ensures no `int` ever reaches `my_function`. This is actually enough to have MyPy accept the code as is, but only because `Callable` means `def (*Any, **Any) -> Any` (i.e. the decorator disables type checking for calling the decorated function).

Comment: Do you only need to reduce types of `A | B` to `A`, or must the construct also handle a separate type `C` that does not get converted to `A`? Do you actually want calling the decorated function to be type checked, or are you fine with ignoring it as in the sample code?

Comment: it must also handle some separate types which don't get converted

Comment: calling the decorated function can be ignored

Comment: or rather - calls to the decorated function can ignore `int` arguments (which will get converted to `str`), but should respect other variables which don't get converted

Comment: Note that while you can't type arguments properly, you still [can](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=d9241e87981827aa9491c98d232d0b62) preserve the return type, which may be quite important. (`wraps` is irrelevant for type checking, it's just a good thing to preserve useful introspection attributes like `__name__`, so that you don't have ton of functions with `__name__` set to `wrapper` and not to original name of `func`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `def` declaration must use the type hints of the arguments actually passed into and out of the function itself. That a decorator or similar wrapper processes arguments or return values is of no concern for the innermost function.
The type checker then takes into account decorators/wrappers only to derive the actual type for calls. At most, a type checker will verify that decorator and inner function are consistent; the decorator does not modify the types of the inner function itself.

For example, a function decorated with [`@contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) must return `:Iterator[T]` and it is up to [the decorator to transform that to `:ContextManager[T]`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/4aae235cefd62ec417b92166d2bcf038cb8801e8/stdlib/contextlib.pyi#L76).

---

For the specific case, this means `my_function` must be annotated with the types it actually handles - namely `(str, str) -> str`. This has the added advantage of making it clear what `a` and `b` mean in the function scope:

```
@decorator  # < this must provide `:str, :str` but can receive whatever it wants
def my_function(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    # ^ the parameter types reflect what actually arrives in the function
    # v in this expression `a: str` and `b: str` in the signature
    return a + b
```

That the *decorated* `my_function` accepts `a: int | str, b: int` is the concern of `decorator`, not `my_function`.